# Convert string to date object without using the format

Tags: java, simpledateformat

Is it possible to convert string to java sql/util Date object without knowing the format of the string value.

Comment: No really.  What does `01/01/01` actually mean?

Comment: Unforunately, there's not really a good way. You could do some pre-checking with regular expressions or else try multiple formats and catch the ParseException (but making errors part of the expected execution flow is usually considered poor practice in java, however python encourages it)

Comment: @MadProgrammer:  My favorite one is 6/7/80.  Am I talking about June 7th, or July 6th?  Am I talking about 1980 or 1080 or even 2180?

Comment: If you knew that the format was (for example) day first, month in the middle, year last, then you could do a reasonable job by splitting on whatever non-digit characters there are with `split("\\D+")`, then using the `GregorianCalendar` constructor directly.  Don't forget to subtract one from the month.  But if you don't know the order of the fields, then there's not much you can do.

Comment: @Makoto Even more ambiguous 06/07/08. Is that YMD, MDY, or DMY? And of course the century issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to know some sort of formatting information. If you have a few ideas, you can just iterate through them.

```
private static String[] formats = new String[] {/* Your list of possible formats */};
public static Date parse(String date) throws ParseException {
    for (String format : formats) {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        try {
            return df.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {}
    }
    throw new ParseException(
            "This date does not conform to any known format", 0);
}
```

Of course, this is only if the same date won't fulfill multiple formats (e.g., 01/01/01 as mentioned in comments)

Comment: break from the loop once  you successfully parse, If I m not wrong

Comment: It does. `return` breaks the loop.

Comment: sorry I missed it. :P

Comment: This response is misleading. Just because the parsing succeeds does'nt mean you have the correct date . Parse fails only if there is some gibbrish in the parsed string.